# How can I add data to a table in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I have tried in many ways but could not add data to the table dynamically
I want to know how to add data in specific cell in a table dynamically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void beforeFines(Form f) {
    try {
        Table tbl = fC.makeTable();
        findTblContainer(f).addComponent(tbl);
        findTblContainer(f).animateLayout(5);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("No fines found!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the model to a new table model with the new data or derive the default model to add the ability to add/remove rows.